# Django - Filter QuerySet only in admin-list and not in admin detail page

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In the Django admin list view, i want to hide products without a name. I just excluded them in the get_query_set() method.

```
 def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.exclude(name=None)
```

This is working perfect, but i want to be able to access products without a name in the admin detail page (with a direct link).
When it try this, i have an error, because it filters the product out of the queryset:
http://127.0.0.1/product/123

> product object with primary key u'123' does not exist.

Is there a workaround for this problem? If possible, without adding a custom filter to the list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could override [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.get_object)

```
def get_object(self, request, object_id, from_field=None):
    """
    Returns an instance matching the field and value provided, the primary
    key is used if no field is provided. Returns ``None`` if no match is
    found or the object_id fails validation.
    """

    model = product
    field = model._meta.pk if from_field is None else model._meta.get_field(from_field)
    try:
        object_id = field.to_python(object_id)
        return model.objects.get(**{field.name: object_id})
    except (model.DoesNotExist, ValidationError, ValueError):
        return None
```

This is undocumented but can be made to work. The standard way though is to use a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you are in `change` or `changelist`

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.resolver_match.url_name == "APPNAME_MODELNAME_changelist":
        return qs.exclude(name=None)
    return qs
```

***Django version***: 1.9